# how to fix problem on No data available in table in data table react js

Tags: reactjs, datatable

I'm new in react js and I want to display all data from database into data table but I'm getting an error of No data available in table. I also added the getStudent to the useEffect so that it would run continuously

this is my useState and useEffect snippet code:

```
const [student, setStudent] = useState([]);

const getStudent = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/admin/get_allstudent");
    const data = await response.json();
    setStudent(data);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
  }
};

const dataTable = () => {
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#example").DataTable();
  });
};

useEffect(() => {
  setInterval(dataTable, 1000);
  getStudent();
}, []);
```

and this is my render:

```
<table id="example" className="display ">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Username</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {student.map((item, index) => {
    return (
    <tr key={item.stu_id}>
      <td>{item.stu_name}</td>
      <td>{item.stu_username}</td>
      <td>
        <Edit item={item} />
        <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={()=> deleteStudent(item.stu_id)}
          >
          Delete
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    );
    })}
  </tbody>
</table>;
```

[And this is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wq2J0.png)

Answer (score 0):

i don't know about jQuery part of  your code and i don't think that is necessary

first try to remove that part and then check if student has value or not

you can check the **student** value by using useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
 if (student) console.log('data is ok ' , student)
}, [student]);
```

if the message showed up in console and it was not empty
then there should be no problem

Comment: this is the result data is ok  Array(1) and I remove the jquery part but the data table is not functioning

Comment: i can't see "no data available" message in the code you shared , there is a row in you output image in table with name "dummy" is this the only data that you are getting from backend ?

Comment: at the first glance it will work but as soon you navigate to other page and go back to that page "no data available" will appear and if you  refresh the page the "no data available" is gone. for the "dummy" it's just for demo purposes. I hope you understand what I'm saying